# Overlapping items in list

Tags: php, html

Recently I've encountered an issue while attempting to create a search form and display the results in a list

```
    <?php 
        require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php"); 
        require_once  ("Includes/connectDB.php");
        include("Includes/header.php");         
     ?>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="searchcontent">
            <?php 
                $querysuccess = FALSE;
                $extsuccess = FALSE;
                if($_GET["query"] != "")
                {
                    echo '<h3>Results for "'.$_GET["query"].'"</h3>';
                    $querysuccess = TRUE;
                }

                if($_GET["ext"] != "*" && $_GET["ext"] != "")
                {
                    echo "<p>Matching extension: *.".$_GET["ext"]."</p>";
                    $extsuccess = TRUE;
                }
                else if($_GET["ext"] == "")
                {
                    echo "<p>No extension specified</p>";
                }
                else
                {
                    $extsuccess = TRUE;
                }

                if($querysuccess == TRUE && $extsuccess == TRUE)
                {
                    doSearch();
                }

                function doSearch()
                {
                    $query = $_GET["query"];
                    $extension = $_GET["ext"];

                    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE";
                    $querycount = 0;

                    $terms = explode(" ", $query);

                    foreach($terms as $word)
                    {
                        $querycount++;
                        if($querycount == 1) {
                            $sql_query .= " description LIKE '%$word%'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $sql_query .= " OR description LIKE '%$word%'";
                        }
                    }

                    if($searchforextension == TRUE)
                    {
                        $sql_query .= "AND extension='$extension'";
                    }

                    mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
                    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

                    $sql_query = mysql_query($sql_query);
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($sql_query);
                    if($numrows > 0)
                    {
                        echo "<ul>";
                        while($proc_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query))
                        {
                            $script_id = $proc_row["id"];
                            $script_name = $proc_row["name"];
                            $script_description = $proc_row["description"];
                            $script_author = $proc_row["author"];
                            $script_authorURL = $proc_row["authorURL"];
                            $script_pathname = $proc_row["filename"];

                            $search_result = "<li><div class='result'>";
                            $search_result .= " <p class='result_title'>$script_name</p>";
                            $search_result .= " <p>$script_description</p>";
                            $search_result .= " <div class='result_footer'>";
                            $search_result .= "     <a href='$script_authorURL'"." class='result_author'>$script_author</a>";
                            $search_result .= "     <a href='/getscript.php?script=$script_id" . "&". "file=$script_pathname' class='result_download'>View</a>";
                            $search_result .= " </div>";
                            $search_result .= "</div></li><br /><br /><br />";
                            echo $search_result;

                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<br/><h2>Unable to find any results matching your query.</h2>";
                    }

                    mysql_close();
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <?php 
        include ("Includes/footer.php");
     ?>
```

I am using Microsoft WebMatrix 2.0 to create this site based upon the PHP starter template, my issue is that when more than 1 object is displayed it overlaps the previous object and screws up the entire layout!

I can post parts of my CSS if required?

**After following Wesley Murch's advice I now have another issue**

[What's not working now http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4498/screenshotgbf.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4498/screenshotgbf.png)

Comment: I will ask again: Does you page now validate or not? http://validator.w3.org/ Until the answer is "Yes", there's nothing you can do with CSS to fix it. Also, your screen shot doesn't say much as you have not described the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're generating invalid HTML.

Here, you close the `<a>` tag with `</p>` which is incorrect:

```
$search_result .= "     <a href='/getscript.php?script=$script_id" . "&". "file=$script_pathname' class='result_download'>View</p>";
```

Here you add `<br>` tags as a direct child of `<ul>` which is invalid:

```
$search_result .= "</div></li><br /><br /><br />";
```

The only valid direct child for a `<ul>` or `<ol>` is `<li>`.

You also open 2 divs at the top of your HTML, but then you have 3 closing tags at the bottom.

Invalid HTML is one of the leading causes of broken layouts. Use this tool in the future as your first stop for debugging HTML and/or CSS:

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: ah how could I make such a juvenile mistake!

Comment: Happens all the time, luckily there are tools for detecting invalid HTML (not referring to myself).

Comment: I would like to add this tip: do *all* your data processing *before* you print the first line of HTML output - it makes things much easier. SQL queries mixed into HTML is a recipe for [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).

Comment: the third closing div is part of the template according to the microsoft documentation.
Here is my new problem now that I've corrected the other issue: http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4498/screenshotgbf.png

Comment: Well in this code, there is no reason for the extra `</div>` at all. Check with the validator. I looked at your screen shot but I don't know what the problem is supposed to be. So, does you HTML page now validate? Don't bother debugging layout until it does.

Comment: My html all checks out fine, even with the third closing div. Now I just need to get the layout working.

Comment: Can you give me a direct link to the page? I see you updated the code in your post, but it's still invalid. I have doubts you're working with valid HTML despite the fact you say it "checks out".

Comment: Here are the erroneous files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/byfhvmiouc85abu/website.zip

I could not find an actual host because of the time at night and I was uber tired.

Comment: I've fixed it, strangely it was the "min-height" css property that stopped it from rendering the page correctly.

Comment: Yeah the zip doesn't help because it didn't contain the necessary files. You could have just pasted your HTML source code output into your post or made a pastie or something.

Comment: Sorry about that, Thankfully it's all fixed now - I still make stupid mistakes in development/debugging even after this long! Time to get back to basics I think..